# How to update a Ruby nested hash inside a loop?

Tags: ruby, rexml

I'm creating a nested hash in ruby rexml and want to update the hash when i enter a loop.

My code is like:

```
hash = {}
doc.elements.each(//address) do |n|
  a = # ... 
  b = # ...
  hash = { "NAME" => { a => { "ADDRESS" => b } } }
end
```

When I execute the above code the hash gets overwritten and I get only the info in the last iteration of the loop.

I don't want to use the following way as it makes my code verbose

```
hash["NAME"] = {}
hash["NAME"][a] = {}
```

and so on...

So could someone help me out on how to make this work...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are unique:

```
hash.merge!({"NAME" => { a => { "ADDRESS" => b } } })
```

Comment: hey thank u very much for ur quick reply.. if i execute the above code its still overwritten.. the variables a and b are alone unique but the "NAME" and "ADDRESS" are different..  so what do i do in this case..

Answer (score 0):

You always create a new hash in each iteration, which gets saved in `hash`.

Just assign the key directly in the existing `hash`:

```
hash["NAME"] = { a => { "ADDRESS" => b } }
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur reply.. In the above code if i have more nested keys like hash["NAME"] = { a => { "ADDRESS" => b , "PLACE" => { "COUNTRY" => d, "REGION" => e } } then the code again becomes lengthy..

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"NAME" => {}}

doc.elements.each('//address') do |n|
  a = ...
  b = ...
  hash['NAME'][a] = {'ADDRESS' => b, 'PLACE' => ...}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blk = proc { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&blk) }

hash = Hash.new(&blk)

doc.elements.each('//address').each do |n|
  a = # ...
  b = # ...
  hash["NAME"][a]["ADDRESS"] = b
end
```

Basically creates a lazily instantiated infinitely recurring hash of hashes.

EDIT: Just thought of something that could work, this is only tested with a couple of very simple hashes so may have some problems.

```
class Hash
  def can_recursively_merge? other
    Hash === other
  end

  def recursive_merge! other
    other.each do |key, value|
      if self.include? key and self[key].can_recursively_merge? value
        self[key].recursive_merge! value
      else
        self[key] = value
      end
    end
    self
  end
end
```

Then use `hash.recursive_merge! { "NAME" => { a => { "ADDRESS" => b } } }` in your code block.

This simply recursively merges a heirachy of hashes, and any other types if you define the `recursive_merge!` and `can_recusively_merge?` methods on them.

Comment: hey this works fine but i want to create the hash in this manner: hash = { "NAME" => { a => { "ADDRESS" => b } } } but this is not updating the hash when entering the loop.